# Problem with jQuery logic. Need to uncheck one checkbox if other is checked, vice versa

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got the code below

If a checkbox is checked, it should uncheck the other, and then show a div. If the other checkbox is checked, it should uncheck the other and show the div.

it works one way round, but not the other. I can't work out how to make it work both ways.

```
    $('#ssUseDates, #isSearchByDate').click(function() {

    if($('#isSearchByDate').attr('checked')) {
        $('#ssUseDates').removeAttr('checked');
        $('#searchDates').show();
    }
    else if($('#ssUseDates').attr('checked')) {
        $('#isSearchByDate').removeAttr('checked');
        $('#searchDates').show();
    }
```

If I check the #ssUseDates box, then check the #isSearchByDate box, it works perfectly, unchecking the #ssUseDates box then showing the div. If I check the #isSearchByDate box, then the #ssUseDates box, it doesn't work, won't let the box check and doesn't uncheck the other.

Thanks for any advice offered.

Comment: which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Why aren't you using a radio button?

Comment: Kei, because by default, none would be checked, and the user must be able to uncheck both. It's just two options that could be chosen, but might not be. Both expose a date range to choose a date with dropdowns, but depending on which checkbox is checked determines how the database returns the results. For example, search by criteria A, or search by criteria B. You can't do both, and might not want to do either. :)

Comment: Fair enough.. How about this then: 3 radio buttons (1 hidden and selected on load, 2 for the options you have). When the page renders, you see 2 unchecked radio buttons :)

Comment: @iCONICA -- see the update to my answer. its short and sweet ^_^

Comment: Hi, Kei. When the page renders, you'll see two unchecked radio buttons, but once you check one, you couldn't uncheck it. The checkboxes IS the correct way of doing it.

Comment: Oh I see. I assumed the user is required to check one. I didn't think about the option of neither one being checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `if...else...` in the shared `click()` is your problem. Try splitting it up:
http://jsfiddle.net/TG2ne/6/

```
$(function() {
    $('#isSearchByDate').click(function() {
        if ($('#isSearchByDate').attr('checked')) {
            $('#ssUseDates').removeAttr('checked');
            $('#searchDates').show();
        } 
    });
    $('#ssUseDates').click(function() {
        if ($('#ssUseDates').attr('checked')) {
            $('#isSearchByDate').removeAttr('checked');
            $('#searchDates').show();
        }
    });
});
```

Alternatively (and less attractively), you could test the id of the clicked element as well:
http://jsfiddle.net/TG2ne/11/

```
$(function() {
    $('#ssUseDates, #isSearchByDate').click(function() {
        if ($(this).attr("id") == "isSearchByDate" && $('#isSearchByDate').attr('checked')) {
            $('#ssUseDates').removeAttr('checked');
            $('#searchDates').show();
        } else if ($(this).attr("id") == "ssUseDates" && $('#ssUseDates').attr('checked')) {
            $('#isSearchByDate').removeAttr('checked');
            $('#searchDates').show();
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Hi, mblase75. The code looks awesome, (the first block). It works almost perfect, but doesn't hide the #searchDates if the user unticks a box. :(

Comment: Hi, I figured that part out myself. :D 

 $(function() {
  $('#isSearchByDate').click(function() {
   if ($('#isSearchByDate').attr('checked')) {
    $('#ssUseDates').removeAttr('checked');
    $('#searchDates').show();
   }
   else{
    $('#searchDates').hide();
   }
  });
  $('#ssUseDates').click(function() {
   if ($('#ssUseDates').attr('checked')) {
    $('#isSearchByDate').removeAttr('checked');
    $('#searchDates').show();
   }
   else{
    $('#searchDates').hide();
   }
  });
 });

Answer (score 0):

Give both the same class name and add a ref to the id you want to show try this:

```
$('.checkClass').change(function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('.checkClass').not(this).attr('checked', false).change();
        $('#'+$(this).attr('ref')).show();
    }
    else {
        $('#'+$(this).attr('ref')).hide();
    }
});
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/9dvDd/5/

Comment: Hi, Neal. Thanks for that, but it doesn't work quite as required. It needs to never allow both checkboxes to be checked at the same time. One being checked should uncheck the other (if checked). The div which they both show is the same div. I've got this:

     $('.chk').change(function() {
  if($(this).is(':checked')) {
   $('#searchDates').show();
  }
  else {
   $('#searchDates').hide();
  }
 });

Comment: @i-CONICA make a fiddle of what you **are** doing, and we shall work from there ^_^

Comment: @neal: i didn't vote your answer down but it's probably because your code doesn't *uncheck* the checkboxes when you check a new one.